# Secondary Subnav underneath main nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a Navigation Bar and when you hover over an item the subnavigation appears below it in a second bar.

I have the nav working with the subnav dropping down straight below it with the code below. Edit: Added an image of the nav as it is working now with the html listed below.

```
          <ul class="main-section-nav nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Main Nav -->
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
              Section
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub">
                <li class="Main">
                    <a href="url.com" title="">Section Name</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="url.com" title="">SubNav Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End Main Nav -->
      </ul>
```

Currently Working:

[image: Currently working Nav]

How I want it to work.

[image: Navigation with Secondary Nav Bar]

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. We need to have the pertinent HTML and CSS in order to see where you are, and what you would like to have happen. You say you have the nav working. What are you asking then?

Comment: @Jeff.Clark I edited it. Hope that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `display: flex;` to the submenu `ul`, that will work just fine.

```css
.open >.dropdown-menu {
  display:flex !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

And what if you set `.dropdown-menu` with static position and from move it from top 50px?

Like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/qaz5cfy8/1